# key simulator always on top/foreground (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to find out how I always have the window in the foreground. If I click on another area, the window is "inactive" and I can no longer access it (which is not the real problem). For example, when I open a browser or a game, I want that to be in the foreground, even when I click on other surfaces. "-topmost" is already available, the window only disappears for other activities.

i post the code for a better overview what i mean (but i myself assume that there will be a small solution if there is one for it )

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        self.style.configure("TButton", background="red",  borderwidth=0, focuscolor="none")
        self.style.configure("TONE.TButton", background="#1e2224", font=("Unispace", 12), borderwidth=1,
                             foreground="#a1e0ff", bordercolor="lime", darkcolor="lime", lightcolor="lightgreen")

        self.bgFrame = []
        for x in range(5):
            frm = Frame(self, bg="red")
            frm.pack(fill="x", ipady=30)
            self.bgFrame.append(frm)

        Button(self.bgFrame[0], text="\u26cc", bg="red", bd=0, command=self.destroy).pack(side="right", anchor="ne")

        self.firstRow = []
        x1 = 0
        width1 = [80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
        for x in range(6):
            firstRow = ttk.Button(self.bgFrame[0])
            firstRow.place(x=x1, y=0, width=width1[x], height=60)
            self.firstRow.append(firstRow)
            x1 += 80

        self.secondRow = []
        x2 = [0, 100, 180, 260, 340, 420, 500]
        width2 = [100, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
        for x in range(6):
            secondRow = ttk.Button(self.bgFrame[1])
            secondRow.place(x=x2[x], y=0, width=width2[x], height=60)
            self.secondRow.append(secondRow)

        x3 = [0, 120, 200, 280, 360, 440, 520]
        width3 = [120, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
        self.thirdRow = []
        for x in range(6):
            thirdRow = ttk.Button(self.bgFrame[2])
            thirdRow.place(x=x3[x], y=0, width=width3[x], height=60)
            self.thirdRow.append(thirdRow)

        self.fourthRow = []
        x4 = [0, 100, 180, 260, 340, 420, 500]
        width4 = [100, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80]
        for x in range(6):
            fourthRow = ttk.Button(self.bgFrame[3])
            fourthRow.place(x=x4[x], y=0, width=width4[x], height=60)
            self.fourthRow.append(fourthRow)

        x5 = 0
        width5 = [100, 100, 100, 300]
        self.fithRow = []
        for x in range(4):
            fithRow = ttk.Button(self.bgFrame[4])
            fithRow.place(x=x5, y=0, width=width5[x], height=60)
            self.fithRow.append(fithRow)
            x5 += 100

        self.bind("<Key>", self.keyBind)
        self.bind("<KeyRelease>", self.keyRelease)

    def keyBind(self, event):
        for i, num in enumerate(range(5), 1):
            if event.char == str(i).upper() or event.char == str(i).lower():
                self.firstRow[i].config(text=event.char.upper(), style="TONE.TButton")
        for i, txt in enumerate(["q", "w", "e", "r", "t"], 1):
            if event.char == str(txt).upper() or event.char == str(txt).lower():
                self.secondRow[i].config(text=event.char.upper(), style="TONE.TButton")
        for i, txt in enumerate(["a", "s", "d", "f", "g"], 1):
            if event.char == str(txt).upper() or event.char == str(txt).lower():
                self.thirdRow[i].config(text=event.char.upper(), style="TONE.TButton")
        for i, txt in enumerate(["<", "y", "x", "c", "v"], 1):
            if event.char == str(txt).upper() or event.char == str(txt).lower():
                self.fourthRow[i].config(text=event.char.upper(), style="TONE.TButton")
        if event.keysym == "Tab":
            self.secondRow[0].config(text="\u2B7E", style="TONE.TButton")
        if event.keysym == "Shift_L":
            self.fourthRow[0].config(text="\u21E7", style="TONE.TButton")
        if event.keysym == "Control_L":
            self.fithRow[0].config(text="STRG", style="TONE.TButton")
        if event.keysym == "Alt_L":
            self.fithRow[2].config(text="ALT", style="TONE.TButton")
        if event.keysym == "space":
            self.fithRow[3].config(text="SPACE", style="TONE.TButton")

    def keyRelease(self, event):
        for i in range(6):
            self.firstRow[i].config(text="", style="TButton")
        for i in range(6):
            self.secondRow[i].config(text="", style="TButton")
        for i in range(6):
            self.thirdRow[i].config(text="", style="TButton")
        for i in range(6):
            self.fourthRow[i].config(text="", style="TButton")
        for i in range(4):
            self.fithRow[i].config(text="", style="TButton")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.geometry("700x340+0+0")

    mw["bg"] = "red"
    mw.overrideredirect(1)
    mw.wm_transient()
    mw.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")
    mw.attributes("-topmost", True)

    mw.mainloop()
```

Comment: In this case you might have to use the `keyboard` library.

Comment: keyboard library? sorry for that question,but I don't know what exactly do you mean

Comment: Right now you want to be able to detect key presses even if the `tkinter` window isn't in focus, right? I don't think you can do that in `tkinter` so you would need to use a library like [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

Comment: yes,  thats what i want. 
ok then thanks for the link, never heard about it.

Comment: I worked on a project similar to screen snipping tool, that uses the same `keyboard` to capture the keystrokes and create hotkeys

Comment: ok thanks for the help, i will keep an eye on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard


class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    # Some constants:
    CHARACTERS_ROW_1 = tuple("qwertyuiop")
    CHARACTERS_ROW_2 = tuple("asdfghjkl")
    CHARACTERS_ROW_3 = tuple("zxcvbnm")
    CHARACTERS = (CHARACTERS_ROW_1, CHARACTERS_ROW_2, CHARACTERS_ROW_3)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.event_queue = []
        self.alive = True

        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("clam")
        self.style.configure("TButton", background="red", borderwidth=0, focuscolor="none", font=("Unispace", 12))
        self.style.configure("TONE.TButton", background="#1e2224", font=("Unispace", 12), borderwidth=1,
                             foreground="#a1e0ff", bordercolor="lime", darkcolor="lime", lightcolor="lightgreen")

        self.buttons = {} # A dictionary of all of the buttons

        for row, characters in enumerate(self.CHARACTERS):
            for column, character in enumerate(characters):
                button = ttk.Button(self, style="TButton")
                button.grid(row=row, column=column)
                self.buttons.update({character: button})

        # Add a global system binding:
        keyboard.hook(self.hook)

        # Start the loop:
        self.handle_events_loop()

        # An easy way to escape the program:
        super().bind("<Escape>", lambda e: self.destroy())

    def destroy(self) -> None:
        self.alive = False
        super().destroy()

    def hook(self, event:keyboard.KeyboardEvent) -> None:
        if self.alive:
            self.event_queue.append(event)

    def handle_events_loop(self) -> None:
        if len(self.event_queue) > 0:
            # Get the first event:
            event = self.event_queue.pop(0)
            if event.name not in self.buttons.keys():
                return None
            if event.event_type == "down":
                self.show_key(event.name)
            elif event.event_type == "up":
                self.hide_key(event.name)
        # After 10 ms call `self.handle_events_loop` again
        super().after(10, self.handle_events_loop)

    def show_key(self, character:str) -> None:
        button = self.buttons[character]
        button.config(text=character, style="TONE.TButton")

    def hide_key(self, character:str) -> None:
        button = self.buttons[character]
        button.config(text="", style="TButton")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = MainWindow()

    # Removed for debugging
    # root.overrideredirect(True)
    root.transient()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.attributes("-transparentcolor", "red")
    root.config(bg="red")

    root.mainloop()
```

I used the `keyboard.hook` to hook to all system wide keyboard events. Then I used a queue with a `tkinter` loop to handle the events.

Comment: hmm, I don't know why, but the process is finishing without doing something before. I installed `keyboard`

Comment: @JoeMo It works for me. I ran it using `cmd` on Windows 10.

Comment: i using windows 10 aswell. I don't get it, i tried it aswell with `cmd` but something is going wrong. but i know that you make good work, and it will works fine. i try to figure it out.

Comment: @JoeMo I still want to figure out the problem :D. Does it give you an error? Do you have the `root.mainloop()` at the end of the code?

Comment: no i click in pycharm on run (or try to start with cmd) and i get this = `Process finished with exit code 0` (and yes i clicked on the main file where I want to run this xD)

Comment: @JoeMo Try adding `print("Test")` after the `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: he shows me `test`after that `Process finished with exit code 0`

Comment: @JoeMo Try running it without using `PyCharm` (using IDLE or double clicking on the file from the file explorer). Also `Process finished with exit code 0` means the program finished without any errors.

Comment: tried it with visual code etc. still something isnt happing. hmm ... lol ... first i thought `super().bind("<Escape>", lambda e: self.destroy())` that was the reason, but then it makes no sence because i need to press this key.

Comment: @JoeMo Lol. I was going to use `Control-W` but decided that it would be better to use `Escape`. Well now I will know to not use `Escape` :D.

Comment: so it looks like something is closing this program... but i don't get it. if I make a new simple app, it still works.

Comment: oh sorry you missunderstood me. that wasn't the reason with `super().bind("<Escape>", lambda e: self.destroy())`

Comment: The only thing that can close the program is the `super().bind("<Escape>", lambda e: self.destroy())`. If you remove that, then there will be nothing in the code that can close the program. How did you install the `keyboard` library? Did you use `python -m pip install keyboard` or something similar?

Comment: ok ... now it works. i saw that you edited your code. i copied it in again and now it works... xDDD

Comment: and it works very well. thanks a lot. one question if its ok what means that : def hide_key(self, character:str) -> None: <-- that none, is there a reason to use it? (i only ask because i don't know)

Comment: @JoeMo The `:str` after the `character` and the `-> None` are there just to tell you the type of variable the program is expecting/will return. You can remove them if you don't like them. They are just there to tell people that read the code stuff about the code.

Comment: no all good. because I know that with ...: bool ...: str ...: int etc but I haven't seen the "None" yet. For me personally, this is important, even if it should only be a visual appearance . well and with the `keyboard` module I will read my way. I don't want a digression. I will get in touch with further questions xD